# The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'TableClient.QueryAsync<T>

Tags: c#, generics, azure-table-storage

I'm using 12.0.0-beta.6 of the Azure.Data.Tables nuget package. When I try to invoke TableClient.GetQueryAsync it gives me the error:

***"The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'TableClient.GetEntityAsync(string, string, IEnumerable, CancellationToken)'"***

I don't see what I'm doing wrong here. Can anybody advice on how to resolve this error?

```
  public async Task<IList<T>> QueryAsync<T>(string queryText, CancellationToken cancellationToken) where T : ITableStorageEntity
        {            
            TableClient tableClient = new TableServiceClient("MY_CONNECTION_STRING").GetTableClient("MY_TABLE_NAME");

            var queryResult = await tableClient.QueryAsync<T>(filter: queryText, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
         
            // prepare and return result list
        }
```

If I add a class constraint to the declaration, like this:

```
  public async Task<IList<T>> QueryAsync<T>(string queryText, CancellationToken cancellationToken) where T : ITableStorageEntity
```

Then these are the errors:

***'T' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'TableClient.QueryAsync(string, int?, IEnumerable, CancellationToken)'***

***The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'TableClient.QueryAsync(string, int?, IEnumerable, CancellationToken)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'T' to 'Azure.Data.Tables.ITableEntity'.***

Comment: If you add `class` as a constraint in addition to the interface, it should resolve the issue.

Comment: It does not, unfortunately. I will edit the question to include what happens when I do that.

Comment: It looks like your method is defined on a class which implements an interface, and you need to update the corresponding method on the interface as well?

Comment: That is true, thank you. I have added the class constraint to the interface's method definition. I added the resulting errors to the question.

Comment: *Now* you're hitting the problem that your method doesn't specify the `new()` constraint, as I explained in my answer. You need to add that as well.

Comment: Thank you, between you and canton7, I believe I have the interface declarations correct now. 

I still get this error:

The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'TableClient.QueryAsync<T>(string, int?, IEnumerable<string>, CancellationToken)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'T' to 'Azure.Data.Tables.ITableEntity'.

Comment: I think you're missing the `Azure.Data.Tables.ITableEntity` bit of the constraint `where T : class, Azure.Data.Tables.ITableEntity, new()`, but without seeing your latest code it's hard to tell

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's look at [the doc for that method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.data.tables.tableclient.queryasync?view=azure-dotnet-preview#Azure_Data_Tables_TableClient_QueryAsync__1_System_String_System_Nullable_System_Int32__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_String__System_Threading_CancellationToken_):

> `public virtual Azure.AsyncPageable<T> QueryAsync<T> (string filter = default, int? maxPerPage = default, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> select = default, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) where T : class, Azure.Data.Tables.ITableEntity, new();`

See that generic type constraint:

> `where T : class, Azure.Data.Tables.ITableEntity, new();`

That means that any `T` you pass in must be a class, must implement `ITableEntity`, and must have a parameterless constructor.

However, your method doesn't enforce this. You only require that `T` implements `ITableStorageEntity`. Your method could theoretically accept something which implements `ITableStorageEntity` but isn't a class, or doesn't have a parameterless constructor, and pass it to Azure's `QueryAsync<T>`, and then what? You've broken the rules!

Your method needs to have the same generic type constraints as `QueryAsync<T>`, or tighter:

```
public async Task<IList<T>> QueryAsync<T>(string queryText, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    where T : class, ITableStorageEntity, new()
```

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful! Always good to read the docs :-) I think I have the Interface declarations correct now. I still have an error, which I described in comments to the answer before yours.

Comment: Great explanation, really helped me understand, thankyou